TypeScriptでimportのパスが認識されない
以下のエラー対処法がわからず困っています。
技術スタックはReact、TypeScript、node.js
MacでVScodeを使用しています。
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../src/router' in '/Users/sumple/test/js_taskList/frontend/src'
発生したタイミングが定かではないのですが、router.tsというファイルが確実に存在しているにも関わらず
何度試しても上記のエラーが発生します。
ディレクトリ構造は以下の通り、App.tsxでrouter.tsをインポートしています。
root
  └── frontend
       └── src
            ├── router.ts
            └── App.tsx

importのパスやファイル名の重複等も確認しましたが、特に異常は発見できておりません。
App.tsxの記述は以下の通りです。
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { fetchData, addData, deleteData, toggleData } from './router';

足りない情報等あればご指摘頂けると嬉しいです。
ご回答の程よろしくお願い致します。
